# try/except in list index out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to rewrite some code for learning purposes and got stuck with implementing `try/except` part into the code.

Class `FilePrep` takes two arguments (`file_name and` path_dir`), the loop checks whether the file exists and returns entire path.

How to properly implement the handler part so error message will be clear rather then throwing `list index out of range`?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
import fnmatch
import os
import errno

class FilePrep:
    def __init__(self, path_dir, file_name):
        self.path = path_dir
        self.file_name = file_name

    def get_source_file_path(self):
        source_file = []

        for file_name in os.listdir(self.path):
            try:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, self.file_name):
                    source_file.append(file_name)
            except IndexError:
                print("file not found")


        source_file_old_name = str(source_file[0])
        file_path = os.path.join(self.path, source_file_old_name)
        
        return file_path
```

Function.py

```
import file_prep

file_path = file_prep.FilePrep('path', 'file_name*.xml')
print(file_path.get_source_file_path())
```

Comment: I think [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70631394/17850902) solves the problem in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mainly problem into the below line:

```
source_file_old_name = str(source_file[0])
```

you can use below solution:

```
try:
    source_file_old_name = str(source_file[0])
except IndexError:
    return ""

file_path = os.path.join(self.path, source_file_old_name)
return file_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Your try/except-block is placed at the wrong place.
Actually, the error occurs, when you're trying to access `source_file[0]`, which is an empty list (`[]`) in case, that no file exists which matches the specified filename.

Therefore, I suggest to change it to the following implementation, where the lenght of the list, which should contain the matched files, is checked. If it is empty, a [`FileNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) will be raised, like so:

```py
        if not source_file:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"No files matching '{self.file_name}'")
```

This results in the following class:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
import fnmatch
import os
import errno

class FilePrep:
    def __init__(self, path_dir, file_name):
        self.path = path_dir
        self.file_name = file_name

    def get_source_file_path(self):
        source_file = []

        for file_name in os.listdir(self.path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, self.file_name):
                source_file.append(file_name)

        if not source_file:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"No files matching '{self.file_name}'")

        source_file_old_name = str(source_file[0])
        file_path = os.path.join(self.path, source_file_old_name)

        return file_path
```